# Add timestamp to filename with msqldump from batch file

Tags: mysql, batch-file, timestamp, backup

I'm trying to add a timestamp to a mysql database dump file with a .bat file but it's not going too well. The timestamp isn't added - i just get a `backup-.sql` file. Any tips?

My file:

```
@echo off
cls
echo Date format = %date%
echo dd = %date:~0,2%
echo mm = %date:~3,2%
echo yyyy = %date:~6,4%
echo.
echo Time format = %time%
echo hh = %time:~0,2%
echo mm = %time:~3,2%
echo ss = %time:~6,2%
echo.
echo Timestamp = %date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%

pushd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
mysqldump --user=root --password=***** leaverequest>c:\backup\backup-%timestamp%.sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

quick edit should fix it:

```
@echo off
cls
echo Date format = %date%
echo dd = %date:~0,2%
echo mm = %date:~3,2%
echo yyyy = %date:~6,4%
echo.
echo Time format = %time%
echo hh = %time:~0,2%
echo mm = %time:~3,2%
echo ss = %time:~6,2%
echo.
set timestamp=%date:~6,4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%

pushd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin"
mysqldump --user=root --password=***** leaverequest>"c:\backup\backup-%timestamp%.sql"
```

Comment: Ok obvious now I see it! Thank - will set as answer in 5 minutes when i'm allowed!

Comment: your welcome, and thanks. ps, dont worry, its the obvious ones we dont think to check for.